# Assembly encryption decryption program

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

The following program compiles and works.
However I cannot figure out what to write for the decryption section.

Can anybody please help me write the corresponding `decrypt_chars()` routine?

```
void encrypt_chars(int length, char EKey)
{
    char temp_char; // char temporary store
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // encrypt characters one at a time
    {
        temp_char = OChars[i]; 
        __asm {                         
            push   eax  // save register values on stack to be safe
            push   ecx          //
            movzx  ecx, temp_char       // 
            lea    eax, EKey                
            call   encrypt     // encrypt the character
            mov    temp_char, al            
            pop    ecx // restore original register values from stack
            pop    eax                  //
        }
        EChars[i] = temp_char;  // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array
    }
    return;

    // --- Start of Assembly code
    __asm {

// Inputs: register EAX = 32-bit address of Ekey, 
//ECX = the character to be encrypted (in the low 8-bit field, CL).
// Output: register EAX = the encrypted value of the source character (in the low 8-bit field, AL).


    encrypt5: push eax
        mov  al, byte ptr[eax]
        push ecx
        and eax, 0x7C
        ror eax, 1
        ror eax, 1
        inc eax
        mov edx, eax
        pop ecx
        pop eax
        mov byte ptr[eax], dl
        xor edx, ecx
        mov eax, edx
        rol al, 1
        ret

    encrypt:
        mov eax, ecx    // get character
        inc eax  

        ret
    }

    //--- End of Assembly code
}
// end of encrypt_chars function


void decrypt_chars(int length, char EKey)
{
    /* needs to be written */

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands right now, it appears that decryption is almost ridiculously trivial. Although the `encrypt5` code attempts to do something rather more elaborate, all that seems to actually be used here is the `encrypt` routine, which simply increments each input (ignoring the key completely), so `A` becomes `B`, `B` becomes `C`, and so on.

As such, the decryption routine can be equally trivial:

```
void decrypt(char *data, int length) {
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        --data[i];
}
```

If you really insist on doing this in assembly language, the core would look something like this:

```
_asm { 
    mov eax, ecx
    dec eax
    ret
}
```

Then you'd do like with the encryption, and invoke that once for each character in the input string.

When/if the encryption is fixed to do something more than just incrementing each input character, the decryption will need to be updated to match. Of course, as it stands right now this encryption doesn't deserve the name "encryption" at all--since it has no key, it offers precisely zero security.

Comment: Right , but I did look how to do the decrypting but still could not figure it out ( as you can see I am kind of new in assemble language )

Comment: Right , but I did look how to do the decrypting but still could not figure it out ( as you can see I am kind of new in assemble language )  I would much appreciate it if somebody can just show me the decryption code so I can actually see and study it .

Comment: is this how you have to start the code or is this from the end ? I am sorry I just don't get it                                                       as I said , I would indeed respectfully insist if you could just help me out decrypting the code ,

Comment: ( I did see many other similar examples on the internet about decrypting but it can be hard to understand , and since this is kind of a small program and if I have directly the answer for it then it can help me to quickly gain the basic understanding about this decrypting program and I can carry on further studying it . )
If it requires some time to write then it is fine I shall wait by the way .
Thank you .

Comment: I suggest you learn to programm in C and Assembler in general before attempting to solve (even) such a ('trivial') task. You already made two posts (using different user names) asking for code instead of answers. This is not what SO is for, however much you respectfully insist.